problem when deploying a build in a vm scale set
This is the error that I have when deploying my pipeline:

[error]EchangeDonneesElectroniques\EchangeDonneesElectroniques\EDE.csproj(365,3): Error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.

I was trying to deploy an application in a windows vmss via Azure DevOps.

You should provide more details, such as what code you have tried.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Hi Joel, have you got the required Microsoft.WebApplication.targets following the questions in my answer?

If you have searched the error, you will find many issues with the similar error.
For example:

v11.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets was not found
Microsoft.WebApplication.targets was not found, on the build server. What's your solution?
MS-Build 2017 "Microsoft.WebApplication.targets " is missing

You can follow the ways in the above questions to get the required Microsoft.WebApplication.targets.
By the way, as you are using the Azure Virtual Machine Scale Set agents, you should customize your VM image with the software you need to make sure your agent always contains the required software.
